# Passing a ref to an HTML element to a custom hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Imagine I have a custom hook that I'll use to add a click event listener into an HTML element.

I create the ref with `const buttonRef = useRef(null);` , so the value on first render is null. The ref value is only assigned in the final of the render method, at a point where my custom hook has already been called.

Therefore, on first render, my custom hook doesn't have anything to add an event listener to.

I end up having to update the component before my custom hook can run for the second time and finally add the event listener to the element. And I get the following behavior:

[image]

[Sandbox with example](https://codesandbox.io/s/9l5lxo3ryy)

**QUESTION:**

How to get around this? Do I really need to force update my component in order to send a ref to a custom hook? Since I only can call hooks and custom hooks at top-level (rules of hooks), something like the following it's not allowed.

```
useEffect(() => {
  useMyHook();
});
```

---

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  const buttonRef = useRef(null);
  const hookValue = useMyHook(buttonRef.current);
  const [forceUpdate, setForceUpdate] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setForceUpdate(prevState => !prevState)}>
        Update Component
      </button>
      <button ref={buttonRef}>Update Hook</button>
      {"This is hook returned value: " + hookValue}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**useMyHook.js (custom hook)**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function useMyHook(element) {
  const [myHookState, setMyHookState] = useState(0);

  console.log("Inside useMyhook...");
  console.log("This is the element received: " + element);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Inside useMyhook useEffect...");

    function onClick() {
      setMyHookState(prevState => prevState + 1);
    }

    if (element !== null) {
      element.addEventListener("click", onClick);
    }
    return () => {
      console.log("Inside useMyhook useEffect return...");
      if (element !== null) {
        element.removeEventListener("click", onClick);
      }
    };
  });

  return myHookState;
}

export default useMyHook;
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The solution is pretty trivial, you just need to pass on the ref to the custom hook instead of `ref.current` since, ref.current is mutated at its original reference when the ref is assigned to the DOM and the useEffect in your custom hook is triggered post the first render, so `buttonRef.current` will reference the DOM node

**useMyHook.js**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function useMyHook(refEl) {
  const [myHookState, setMyHookState] = useState(0);

  console.log("Inside useMyhook...");
  console.log("This is the element received: ", refEl);

  useEffect(() => {
    const element = refEl.current;
    console.log("Inside useMyhook useEffect...");

    function onClick() {
      console.log("click");
      setMyHookState(prevState => prevState + 1);
    }
    console.log(element);
    if (element !== null) {
      element.addEventListener("click", onClick);
    }
    return () => {
      console.log("Inside useMyhook useEffect return...");
      if (element !== null) {
        element.removeEventListener("click", onClick);
      }
    };
  }, []);

  return myHookState;
}

export default useMyHook;
```

---

**index.js**

```
function App() {
  const buttonRef = useRef(null);
  const hookValue = useMyHook(buttonRef);
  const [forceUpdate, setForceUpdate] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setForceUpdate(prevState => !prevState)}>
        Update Component
      </button>
      <button ref={buttonRef}>Update Hook</button>
      {"This is hook returned value: " + hookValue}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[**Working demo**](https://codesandbox.io/s/7j8v10y87q)

Comment: Could you clarify why the `if (element !== null) {` tests are required inside the hook?