# Is using a ref in a custom hook feasible or advised for mutating the DOM?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am working on incorporating a 3rd-party library into a React app, and hooks are making this very easy overall.
However I have encountered a few issues, and I was hoping for some clarity on what is going on 'under the hood'.

For simplicity, let's say this is my 3rd-party code that mutates the DOM directly:

```
const renderStuff = (div, txt) => {
  if(div) div.innerHTML = txt;
}
```

And my component is something like this:

```
export const EffectRender = () => {
  const divRef = useRef();
  useRenderer(divRef, "Hello, world");
  return <div ref={divRef}></div>;
}
```

Here is the proposed custom hook:

```
const useRenderer = (ref, txt) => {
  const div = ref.current;
  useEffect(() => {
    renderStuff(div, txt);
  },[div, txt])
};
```

This works if one of the params (in this case, `txt`) is late-updated, say as a result of an async load.
But the `useEffect` never recognizes when the `ref.current` value changes.
So if the `txt` is set before `ref.current` is set (as in this case) the component never renders.

I understand that I can fix that by using `setState` in the custom hook, as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56136601/passing-a-ref-to-an-html-element-to-a-custom-hook).
But this starts to feel cumbersome.

I also understand that I could put the `renderStuff` call in a `useEffect` hook on the main component, and that guarantees the ref.current is set.
So: `useEffect(() => { renderStuff(divRef.current, txt); },[txt]);` is fine.

My question really is whether this whole approach of using a ref inside a custom hook is a good idea.
Is there a simpler way of getting the hook to recognize when the ref has changed?
Or is this a case where custom hooks are not suited to the task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `const div = ref.current;` in `useRenderer` is declared outside of the hook. In this moment of the cycle the ref is still not assigned, so its value is `null`.

If I understood the issue correctly, then the solution is to simply move the ref inside the `useEffect` callback. This is one of your proposals and I believe its the correct way:

```
const useRenderer = (ref, txt) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const div = ref.current;
        renderStuff(div, txt);
    }, [txt]);
};
```

`useEffect` dependencies will not trigger when the ref the changes. This is ok in your case as the ref already has its assigned value when `useEffect` runs. However, if the ref changed and you needed to track the change the way to go is using a `useState`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That works great! FYI: in the proposal you mention, I was assuming the `useEffect` had to be in the original component. I'm beginning to see where my thinking has gone wrong - the assumption is that the `useEffect` has to detect when the `ref.current` gets set. But that is not the case at all.

Comment: I'm glad it worked! Using `useEffect` inside a hook, is equivalent to having it directly in the component, but in a more convenient/sharable way.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [Alvaro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1176359/alvaro) for clarifying the issue. I want to explain where my thinking went wrong here, assuming I'm not the only one to make this mistake.

### My bad logic

We use `effect` hooks because the code is mutating the DOM, and `useEffect` exists to handle exactly this sort of side-effect.

We use `ref` hooks to connect to a given DOM element. The `ref` instance is like a singleton, in that the instance doesn't change during the life of the app. Only the `ref.current` property changes.

And directly under the relevant section in the [hooks reference docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) I read this:

> Keep in mind that useRef doesn’t notify you when its content changes.
>   Mutating the `.current` property doesn’t cause a re-render.

From that, I understood that relevant dependencies need to be passed to the `useEffect` call. And that the element to be updated (in `ref.current`) was one of these dependencies. And since changing the `ref.current` property doesn't trigger a re-render, it presumably wasn't triggering the `useEffect` call either.

BTW: this thinking was reinforced by `es-lint` demanding I add `ref.current` (in my case, `div = ref.current`) into the dependencies list: `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'div'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.` I always trust the linter, of course.

My conclusion: there was no simple way to use an `effect` hook to render to a `ref` instance. I needed to put the `ref.current` into a `useState` setter somehow. Ugly!

### My core assumption

I assumed that the way the `useEffect` handles side-effects is not relevant. The `effect` hook is a black-box buried in the bowels of the `typescript` source code, and it moves in mysterious ways.

But the only thing 'buried' was this sentence in the [use-effect docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect):

> The function passed to useEffect will run after the render is
>   committed to the screen.

"*After* the render". Of course. That is *how* `useEffect` handles side-effects, by guaranteeing not to run until the DOM is ready to go.

### The solution

As Alvaro's answer suggests, make sure to read the `ref.current` property *inside* the `useEffect` hook. The `ref` never changes, and `ref.current` is guaranteed to be already populated with a DOM element.

As usual, it is obvious in hindsight. Thanks again, Alvaro.